# CodeIgniter: How to match current_url against views url (to construct a nav)

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, base-url

In order to apply the active class to the current item in the navigation menu. I need to check if its link is equal to the URL

I am trying like this:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php if(uri_string(current_url()) == base_url() || uri_string(current_url()) == '') echo 'active'; ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if(uri_string(current_url()) == base_url('news/create/')) echo 'active'; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('news/create/') ?>">+ New</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Wich seems to work fine with the home

But in news/create won't ever be equal....

It compares **news/create** (`uri_string(current_url()`) with **/news/create** (`base_url('news/create')`)

So.. what's **the way** to go with this issue?

Comment: Why not just do `if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'news/create')` ?

Comment: Looks cleaner to me! Post it as an answer

Comment: Just posted the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said, a clean and simple solution:

```
if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'news/create'){ ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<?php if(! $this->uri->segment(1) || $this->uri->segment(1) == 'welcome') echo 'active'; ?>">
         <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if($this->uri->segment(1) == 'news' && $this->uri->segment(2) == 'create' ) echo 'active'; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('news/create/') ?>">+ New</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's simple.. That's what counts ;)

Comment: I do agree with him/her. You just need to know which controller and action is called!

Comment: My suggestion above, `if($this->uri->uri_string() == 'news/create')`is slightly less messy though :)